# Apache return blank page in IE, chrome download all files

Tags: apache, networking, apache2, vmware

I upgraded my ubuntubox from 10.10 to 11.04 and after that i have problem.

- If i execute http://oller.angst.nu/phpinfo.php or test.txt in windows and IE it return a blank page. If i look at the source i see header information.
- If i execute the same sites with chrome, files are downloaded and contains the same information.
- If i execure the same sites from a linux box it works.
- If i execute any php-script with php-cli it works.
- If i execute a site with wget it works.

I have tried different windows computers.

I have googled around alot but cant find any similar problem.

Comment: It seems to be my f*ck*ng router? Linksys E4200. I have an other portforward rule to http://oller.angst.nu:1337 and that works.

Comment: It worked because the other virtual server had a network adapter with type flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The server is virtual (VMware ESXi 4.1) and had a network adapter typ of E1000.

*E1000 — An emulated version of the Intel 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet NIC. A driver for this NIC is not included with all guest operating systems. Typically Linux versions 2.4.19 and later, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition and later, and Windows Server 2003 (32-bit) and later include the E1000 driver.*

*Note: E1000 does not support jumbo frames prior to ESX/ESXi 4.1.*

Source: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001805

I switched to VMXNET3 and it all works again.

Good to know is that when i tried to connect with putty and SSH, some computers gave the message *Incoming packet was garbled on decryption*